# Select the last modified file from a folder and compress it

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I have a directory, where log files are created periodically.
I want to fetch the last created file, compress it and store to a destination directory.

Currently, I just compress the file access just the filename using 
7z.exe a source destination
Now, I need to create a batch file using Power Shell to fetch the recent created and compress.
plz help.
I'm not a programmer.

Comment: in the question title you want the last modified file ,but in the question it is the the last created...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$pathTo7zip = "<path to your copy of 7zip>\7z.exe"
$sourceFolder = "<path to your log folder>"
$destinationFolder = "<path to where you want to put the ZIP files>"

$newestSourceFileName = get-childitem -Path $sourceFolder | 
    where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 
    Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | 
    Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Name

& $pathTo7zip a "$destinationFolder\logfile.zip" "$sourceFolder\$newestSourceFileName"
```

Only 3 elements to this script;

1. Definition of the relevant paths
2. Finding the name of the most recently created file:

   `get-childitem -path $sourceFolder` - returns all files/folders in the source folder

   `where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }` - filter out any folder objects

   `Sort-Object -Property CreationTime`  - sort the objects in order of CreationTime

   `Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Name` - select the first item in the list (ie newest file) and return the `name` property
3. Call 7Zip with necessary parameters to create the ZIP file.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %A in ('dir *.txt /b /a-d /o-d') do makecab "%A" "%~nA.cab" & goto :EOF
```

will take last text file and put it in a cab file. See `dir /?` and the `/t` switch to control modified/created.

In a batch file use %%A rather than %A used at the command prompt.